# Wordpress php use wp_nav_menu to display all pages in menu

Tags: arrays, wordpress, menu

I am currently building a wordpress theme. For the menu, I just want to display all the pages that are created in the order that they are created in (i.e. I don't want users to have to go into the 'menu' section of the site and create their own).

I tried using wp_page_menu and this worked HOWEVER I need to add a walker class to expand the functionality, which you can't do with this function. So I need a way to display all my pages with using wp_nav_menu as my code - is there a way to do this?

Here is my code currently:

```
<nav id="nav">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'walker' => new Clapton_Nav_Walker ) ); ?>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

functions.php this below code register a menu for use

```
 <?php register_nav_menu( 'main_menu', 'Primary Menu' ); ?> 
// remove <?php ?> tags if it already there
```

index.php or wherever you want, below code output the menu

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main_menu','walker' => new Clapton_Nav_Walker ) ); ?>
```

Build menu in WordPress Dashboar -> Appearance -> Menus -> Manage Locations

Comment: Thanks @Manjesh V but in my question I said "I don't want users to have to go into the 'menu' section of the site and create their own" I just want the menu to be dynamically created when a user creates page